# Cookie not set in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie when user logs in to Flask portal but for some reason it always returns null.

Here is where I set the cookie:

```
res = make_response("Setting a cookie for user login")
res.set_cookie('authenticated', value='yes', domain='127.0.0.1', max_age=60*60*8)
app.logger.info(request.cookies.get('authenticated'))
```

Output:

`INFO:flask.app:None`

Equally when I try to retrieve the cookie from the next redirect location it prints the same.

Comment: first you have to send it to client before you can check it in `request`. Do you access page using `http://127.0.0.1` ? You could also check in browser in `DevTools` tab `Store` to see if it has some cookies for your page.

Comment: This looks like a job for Insomnia.

Comment: @furas, its the same when I send it. I added the domain because multiple parts of the server run on different ports